# Dowloading Word docs python

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

for my Coursework, I have to build a web scraper which scapes the website for img, word docs and pdf and downloads them to a file, I have got the img downloading work but when I change the code to download docs or pdf, it doesn't find any at all, I using beautifulsoup to scrape the website, and I know there are docs and pdf's on the website just unable to get them downloaded.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import shutil
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import sys
import time
import os
import url
import hashlib
import re

url = 'http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~40009856/CW/'

path=('c:\\temp\\')

def ensure_dir(path):
    directory = os.path.dirname(path)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(directory) 
    return path

os.chdir(ensure_dir(path))

def webget(url): 
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    return html

def get_docs(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    docutments = [docs for docs in soup.findAll('doc')]
    print (str(len(docutments)) + " docutments found.")
    print('Downloading docutments to current working directory.')
    docutments_links = [each.get('src') for each in docutments]
    for each in docutments_links:
        try:
            filename = each.strip().split('/')[-1].strip()
            src = urljoin(url, each)
            print ('Getting: ' + filename)
            response = requests.get(src, stream=True)
            # delay to avoid corrupted previews
            time.sleep(1)
            with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
        except:
            print('  An error occured. Continuing.')
    print ('Done.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     get_docs(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read what .find_all()  and other methods do: [.find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=find_all#find-all)

First argument of .find_all() is a tag name. It was OK for

```html
<img src='some_url'>
```

tags. You got all img tags with soup.find_all('img'), extracted all urls to actual files and downloaded them.

Now you are looking for tags like

```html
<a href='some_url'></a>
```

with urls containing '.doc'. Something like this should do it:

```
soup.select('a[href*=".doc"]')
```

Comment: @akozi I don't know any other way to insert html tags in answer. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

More of an aside but you can use OR CSS selector syntax to combine pdf,docx etc. Note you still need to complete some paths e.g. with prefixing `"http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~40009856/CW/"`. The following uses [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) css selector syntax with $ operator (this means value of attribute string ends with)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url= 'http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~40009856/CW/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
items = soup.select("[href$='.docx'], [href$='.pdf'], img[src]")
print([item['href'] if 'href' in item.attrs.keys()  else item['src'] for item in items])
```

Comment: Did you try this?